# How can I create a sweet pizza that looks like pizza?

Tags: pizza, dessert

Looking for a bit of inspiration for an idea I have. I want to serve 3 courses of pizza: starter, main and dessert. It's a gimmick, I know, but a fun one I think.

Got the starter and main nailed, but as neither of these will look much like a standard pizza, **I wanted the dessert to look just like a pizza**.

My (as yet untested) idea is to make a slightly sweeter base (not too sweet, toppings will add sweetness) and for toppings I am thinking:

- Rasberry Jam (as the red base)
- Mascarpone and peanut butter (as the cheese, peanut butter to add a little crunch)
- Caramelised Sugared banana slices (hopefully, these will come out brown enough to look a little like pepperoni)

Will the above work?  If so, do you have any suggestions for the execution?  If not, what should I do instead?

Comment: I have edited your question to tighten it up a little (per standards here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and hopefully provide the answers you are looking for.  If I have changed it too substantially from your intent, please feel free to edit it again.

Comment: I feel they are pretty semantic issues, not really changing the essence at all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you make the base neutral - a typical Neopolitan dough would do - you could use white chocolate shavings to give an appearance of cheese as well.  I would keep the amount light.

While looking to verify this idea, I found a [recipe](http://www.eatingwell.com/recipes/dessert_pizza.html) that gave me a few more pieces of inspiration.  Instead of carmelized sugar banana slices, try dried fruits (strawberries, sweetened cranberries, raspberries, etc.) for your toppings.  These will look like sausage bits or pepperoni.  You can also use pineapple and make it look like a Hawaiian pizza.

You could also use [almond cream](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/373457#2318569) as a white sauce or as some of your cheese for a richness that is not too sweet.

Comment: Ooh, that recipe looks yummy, and it's giving me ideas: if your cake-decorating skills are up to it, you could make fondant or marzipan mushrooms; and chopped toasted hazelnuts could look a bit like sausage.

Comment: @Marti I once did marzipan mushrooms for a birthday cake and my son (then 4) refused to eat ... his favorite cake. He was sure our cat mistakenly used it.

Comment: Use sweet roll dough for the base. I think a standard pizza base would clash a bit.

Answer (score 6):

I'd try something like brioche- or challah-type dough + raspberry jam + white chocolate shavings + raspberry fruit leather cut into rounds with a cookie cutter. It could also work with a shortbread dough - think Linzer cookies. (Just make sure to choose a softer shortbread rather than a crispy one, otherwise it'll be very hard to slice.) If you don't oversweeten the crust and use a good raspberry jam (perhaps a no-sugar-added all-fruit one), it shouldn't be too sweet, and raspberries & white chocolate is always a good combination.

Comment: Hey! this one sounds a very un-pizza dessert! I like it! :)

Answer (score 5):

In parts of Germany they make a dish called Flammkuchen, which is a type of pizza. A traditional savoury topping is bacon + sour cream + onion, and a traditional sweet topping is sliced apple with Calvados and cream. I've eaten both versions, in Heidelberg and in the Black Forest, and I recommend them heartily.

Here are some recipes. I've not made them, so I can't vouch for them.

http://www.chefkoch.de/rs/s0/apfel+flammkuchen/Rezepte.html

Comment: welcome.  Do these dishes look like a typical American pepperoni pizza, or could one be made to?  If so, how?

Comment: They are thin-crust, but otherwise look like normal pizzas. Here are some pictures of Flammkuchen with different toppings: http://www.nicoletta-backtechnik.de/flamm.php

Comment: Basically, it's just a thin-crust pizza, topped with sour cream + sugar + grated lemon rind, and then with sliced apples and chopped nuts. I like it without too much sour cream. They should be cooked in a very hot oven (gas mark 7).

Comment: To make it look like a pepperoni pizza, I would: (1) make a thin base of sweetened apple puree as for an apple tart, maybe tinted with a little bit of raspberry puree, (2) top it with the sour cream mixture, (3) top it with rounds of sliced apple and rely on cooking to change their colour, or rounds of sliced firm plum/peach.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider docked puff pastry (poked with little holes so it doesn't puff much) for your crust. It'll be light and buttery and a good foil for the sweet stuff you put on.

I'd think about doing grilled stone fruits like peaches, plums or nectarines, or maybe some grilled pineapple. These items can be pan seared effectively too. This stuff won't look like a regular pizza much, but they'll be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

**Chocolate pizza**

[image]  [recipe](http://www.copykat.com/2009/02/06/ci-cis-chocolate-dessert-pizza/)

**Cherry pizza**

[image]  [recipe](http://www.copykat.com/2009/02/06/ci-cis-cherry-pizza/)

**Fruit pizza**

[image] [recipe](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dessert-Pizza/)

Comment: Crumb topping as cheese - interesting.

Comment: Yeah, the crumb topping looks like grated Parmesan at best, and I don't think I've ever had a pizza with *just* Parmesan on it. (Plenty of pizza places put out shakers of grated cheese, but that's in addition to the melted mozzarella that's already on the pizza.)

Comment: @Marti "Se miente mas de la cuenta por falta de fantasía, también la verdad se inventa" ... bad translation -> Most lies are due lack of imagination, reality is also an invention (Antonio Machado)  :D

Comment: These are good links (and great photos), but generally answers here should be usable without having to follow a link.  Not that you should reprint the entire recipes here, but try to give us the basic idea (i.e. by describing it as a chocolate pie using pizza dough for the crust and crumb topping to simulate the appearance of cheese).  Otherwise, if the links ever break then so does the answer.

Comment: @Aaronaut In this particular case I rather prefer not to endorse any "pizza as a dessert" recipe. I gathered the images and protected them from the eventual disappearance from their servers, by using SE proposed servers, giving credit where is due. "Pizza as a dessert" as the OP says very clearly is just a gimmick, so I feel the photographs are more important than the recipes. The taste of a dessert with a dough __similar__ to pizza is ...

Comment: @belisarius - why does it have to be just a gimmick?  The OP's "gimmick" comment applied to making all the courses be pizza based.  Pizza as dessert deserves our culinary attention as much as anything.  I refuse to believe it couldn't be done well.

Comment: @justkt You have the right to (written with my mouth busy munching home-made Crème brûlée ) :D

Comment: If you don't actually endorse the content of your answer then either don't post it, or post it with disclaimers.  As is, your answer just isn't complete; one has to follow the links to actually understand anything you're talking about.  This is more or less like posting a Wikipedia link as your answer; it's fine for certain types of questions **if** and **only if** you actually quote or paraphrase the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea to make a cookie cake that looks like pizza:

- chocolate chip cookie crust
- jam for sauce
- shaved coconut for cheese
- fruit roll-ups for pepperoni
- green gummy bears for peppers

Answer (score 1):

You could also go for a white pizza (usually uses a cream or pesto sauce instead of tomato). Start with a neutral dough as recommended above and add a layer of cream cheese icing for the sauce. I'd go with coconut shavings for the cheese, as they'll brown a little bit and give some contrast to the sauce. White pizza doesn't usually have toppings beyond cheese, olive oil and spices, so the only other thing I would put on is some fresh chopped mint leaves as it comes out of the oven.

Answer (score 0):

I've had chocolate spread and marshmallow pizza before, however it is extremely sweet.  It was more a gimmick than a serious dish.

I'd guess by using less sweet chocolate spread and experimenting with different marshmallows, perhaps with the addition of chopped nuts, mint leaves or maybe something like a raspberry sauce could make something worth eating.

Answer (score 0):

I've thoroughly enjoyed dessert pizzas from a local pizza shop:

1. Banana, berries, chocolate (white and milk), custard
2. Apple & cinnamon, apricot, crumble, custard, berries

They are both delicious!

Answer (score -1):

a cinnamon bun pizza

Sweet Yeast Dough rolled out
Drizzle with melted butter with cinnamon & icing sugar
Bake & drizzle with milk based icing!

Comment: This won't really look like a pizza, given the color and consistency difference in the toppings.